# In Monopoly, can you save an 'advance' card to use later?

Tags: house-rules, monopoly

Playing with friends, and they give me this rule I've never heard of before, can't find any info.

They say you can save an '**advance token**' card (like a go to jail card) to use at any time.
Their reasoning is because it says '**advance token**' *instead* of '**advance to**', even though it says '**advance token to**'.

Is this legitimate?

Comment: Do you mean a community chest or chance card?

Comment: FWIW, this does seem like one of the *less* game-breaking house rules I've heard of, but it is a house rule.

Comment: Do your friends realise that the card isn't an "advance token", but instead is instructing the player to advance their token (i.e. playing piece) to the stated location?

Comment: @AndyT Ah, brilliant observation. I hadn't noticed the confusion that might arise from the parallel to, for example, token cards from Magic: The Gathering.

Answer (score 12):

No. Cards are resolved when drawn (except for Get Out Of Jail, by explicit card text).

> #### CHANCE AND COMMUNITY CHEST
>
> When you land on either of these spaces, take the top card from the deck indicated, follow the instructions and return the card face down to the bottom of the deck. The "Get Out of Jail Free" card is held until used and then returned to the bottom of the deck.

[Source : Hasbro - Rules of Monopoly](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf)

The wording choice of "advance token to" versus "advance to" is a distinction without a difference: the token in question is the player's playing piece, i.e., the pawn: top hat, shoe, racecar, whatever.

In the case of cards that say to advance your token, you must advance your token to the designated space when the card is drawn.